# write extern C and C++ both compiler

Tags: c++

How I can fix this problem. Look to program en the extern C and C++ code.
The program is good. How you can write a good C and C++ code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include “myccode.h”

void dchar(char c)
{
    printf ("%d\n",(int)c);
}

void main()
{
    dchar(128);
}
```

On the screen has to be 128 but, you get -128. They told me write a extern C code. Me and my friend wrote for both C en C++ code compiler, but nothing happened. We still get -128.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Please take a little time to learn the formatting rules, e.g. via the Editing and Formatting section in the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)  - it is very hard to read questions if code is not properly formatted.

Comment: Just for your information, that casting of `c` to `int` in the call to `printf` isn't needed. For variable-argument functions like `printf` all smaller integer types (e.g. `char` and `short`) are automatically converted to `int`.

Comment: I have put the complete programm again with desrciption this time.  This my hearderfile myccode.h for the program for both compiler

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif
#if defined(__STDIOC__) || defined(__cplusplus)
extern void function(int,char,long,float,double,unsigned)  //  for all overloading function
extern void* cplusplus_callback_function();
#else
extern void function();
extern void* cplusplus_callback_function(); 

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

Answer (score 1):

`char` is typically a signed type holding one byte, even though that's up to the compiler (thanks commenters for pointing that out). It can therefore hold numbers from -128 to +127.
Thus, 128 is first converted to a char (causing an overflow, being converted to -128), and then back to int.
To print 128, you have to use a type which can hold this value. This could be for example an `unsigned char`:

```
#include <cstdio>

void dchar(unsigned char c)
{
    printf ("%u\n",c);
}

int main()
{
    dchar(128);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
128
```

Comment: `char` *can* be a signed type, it's totally up to the compiler.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks! didn't know that. default on current (desktop) compilers though is to have it signed, right? Or is there any compiler which does otherwise?

Comment: @codeling For X86/64, GCC and MSVC (and maybe others) can do both, depending on the flags when calling the compiler.

Comment: I have put the complete programm again with desrciption this time.  This my hearderfile myccode.h for the program for both compiler

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif
#if defined(__STDIOC__) || defined(__cplusplus)
extern void function(int,char,long,float,double,unsigned)  //  for all overloading function
extern void* cplusplus_callback_function();
#else
extern void function();
extern void* cplusplus_callback_function(); 

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

Comment: @dyana what is your question? prolonged code fragments are furthermore not suitable for comments, please edit question if there's more info from your side...

Comment: I have put the complete programm again with desrciption this time.  This my hearderfile myccode.h for the program for both compiler

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif
#if defined(__STDIOC__) || defined(__cplusplus)
extern void function(int,char,long,float,double,unsigned)  //  for all overloading function
extern void* cplusplus_callback_function();
#else
extern void function();
extern void* cplusplus_callback_function(); 

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

Comment: @dyana repeating the same comment a second time won't make it more clear :(

Comment: How I can write a exten .h headerfile for this program. It is not I but They will accept the program only with a .h headerfile.
I never had write a .h headerfile be fore. I need help or Help me. It must be with extern { ... } for this program.
That is the way they won it. The nummer 128 has to be op the screen.

#include <stdio.h>

void dchar(char c)
{printf ("%d\n",(int)c);}

extern void dchar (unsigned char);

void main()

{dchar(128);}

Answer (score 1):

The range of values a `char` can support, for your compiler, is `-128` to `127`.    It is implementation defined whether a `char` is equivalent to a `unsigned char` or `signed char`, and your compiler vendor has chosen the latter.

Converting a value of `128` to a `signed char` that cannot represent the value `128` gives undefined behaviour.   So any result is possible from your code.

Your only options would be to change your function so it accepts an integral argument of a type that can represent the value of `128`.   Options might include `unsigned char` (the standard guarantees it can represent values between `0` and `255`) or `int` (which is guaranteed able to represent values between `-32767` and `32767` - and, depending on compiler, may support a larger range).

The "right" solution depends on the range of values for which you require your function to produce correct output.   You have not given any information about what values you need your code to work with other than `128`, so that is an answer you will need to work out for yourself.

And, BTW, `main()` returns `int`, not `void` in standard C++.

Comment: I have put the complete programm again with desrciption this time.  This my hearderfile myccode.h for the program for both compiler

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif
#if defined(__STDIOC__) || defined(__cplusplus)
extern void function(int,char,long,float,double,unsigned)  //  for all overloading function
extern void* cplusplus_callback_function();
#else
extern void function();
extern void* cplusplus_callback_function(); 

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

Answer (score 0):

First I want to thank you for your time and solution. Both program works.
I ask you again to watch the program but, this time with the complete description.
This is the complete program including description.

## include

void dchar(char c)
{printf ("%d\n",(int)c);}

dchar the function is simple and press the numeric value of the passed to the function sign off.
What do you think can go wrong in such a simple function, especially when there type security is provided.
You can check this by compiling this short source file separately. Then enter the following source and compile it into position.

extern void dchar (unsigned char); I forgot last time, Sorry

void main()

{dchar(128);}

Everything seems to be normal until you try to run the linked program. Instead of weathered deed value 128
The value -128 is displayed. There has been an incomparable view type conversion so that the numerical value is wrong
was interpreted. The process of mangling function did not even have a chance to prevent this.
To resolve this problem by using well-written header files. Write the external declaration in a .h header files and use #include
To add the header file. Naturally, even now that there are errors do occur, but the probability of this method is dramatically reduced.